# multiple if conditions optimisation

Tags: c, algorithm, arduino

I am building a simple C project (for arduino) and I have come across this question.It's not actually that language specific, it's more of an algorithm optimisation thing.

So, I need to check a value of X against a sensor reading.

```
If X <5 ...
else if x<10...
else if x<15...
else if x<20...
```

Then in each clause I have the same for loop,but the iterations change depending on the value of X.

In a general sense, how can these if conditions be replaced by something unified?I remember these "gradation" or "leveling" problems in highschool, but we still used if clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment below you've said (in reference to the second solution under the bar using an array):

> I actually do not need the second dimension,as the value ranges are defined in the first dimension/column (5 10 15 20 etc)

In that case, it's really much simpler than the solutions below:

```
int loops = ((X / 5) + 1) * 5;
```

...assuming `X` is an `int`. That uses integer division, which truncates (e.g., `4 / 5` is `0`), adds one, then multiplies the result by 5. Here's the same thing in JavaScript just for an on-site example (in JavaScript, since numbers are always floating point, we have to add in a flooring method, but you don't need that in Java):

```js
var X;
for (X = 0; X < 25; ++X) {
  var loops = (Math.floor(X / 5) + 1) * 5;
  console.log("X = " + X + ", loops = " + loops);
}
```

---

> Then in each clause I have the same for loop,but the iterations change depending on the value of X.

I'd set a variable to the number of iterations, then put the `for` loop after the `if`/`else` sequence.

```
int loops;
if (X < 5) {
    loops = /*whatever*/;
} else if (X < 10) {
    loops = /*whatever*/;
} else if (X < 15) {
    loops = /*whatever*/;
// ...and so on...
} else {
    loops = /*whatever for the catch-all case*/;
}
for (int i = 0; i < loops; ++i) {
    // ...
}
```

If you're trying to avoid the `if`/`else`, if there are only a small number of possible sensor values, you could use a `switch` instead, which in some languages is compiled to a jump table and so fairly efficient.

If you want to have the ranges held as data rather than in an `if`/`else` sequence, you could use an array of values:

```
int[][] values = {
    {5, 500},
    {10, 700},
    {15, 800},
    {20, 1200},
    {0, 1500}  // 0 is a flag value
};
```

(There I'm using an array of `int[]`, but it could be a nice clean class instance instead.)

Then loop through the array looking for the first entry where `X < entry[0]` is true (or where `entry[0]` is `0`, to flag the last entry).

```
int loops = 0; // 0 will never be used, but the compiler doesn't know that
for (int[] entry : values) {
    if (entry[0] == 0 || X < entry[0]) {
        loops = entry[1];
        break;
    }
}
```

...followed by the `for` loop using `loop`s.

Comment: That is actually one step ahead in this specific situation, I intended to put the for loops inside the ifs but your post makes ultimate sense(and makes me look like a fool XD )
But Im looking for a way to get rid of the if conditions completely.
What if I have 100 different conditions (or ranges)
And nope, I get a variety of sensor values so it's more of a range/gradation/level/idk problem

Comment: @JohnGkikas: Hmm, the alternative I just posted may be of some use, but if not, it would probably be good to post more information about the range and distribution of sensor inputs so people can tackle it from a levelling perspective.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed. I actually do not need the second dimension,as the value ranges are defined in the first dimension/column (5 10 15 20 etc) 
But still this is so elegant! How did not I think of this earlier.

Comment: @JohnGkikas: Ah! In that case, it's much simpler: `int loops = ((X / 5) + 1) * 5;` (I've updated the post).

Answer (score 0):

Since your intervals are products of 5, it may be possible to just divide X by 5 and use the result as index in an array.

```
const size_t loops[] = {someval, anotherval, ..., lastval};
size_t i,  nloops = loops[X / 5];
for (i = 0; i < nloops; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes :) I already tried this and it works, but I'm trying to tackle this problem in a more generic scale 
Think of 100 different conditions, each condition having a seemingly random number (so the interval- or any other function of x cannot be used as a iteration)